# moving multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: mv

I have a directory, within are many directories (abc1 abc2 abc3 etc.) that contain a sub-directory - always the same name (MATCHING_STRING) - full of files. I want to remove that sub-directory (MATCHING_STRING), keeping files in their own abc# directory. I don't want all files ending up in 1 location as would happen with `mv */* .`

before:

Main/
├─ abc1/
│  ├─ MATCHING_STRING/
│  │  ├─ xyz1
│  │  ├─ xyz2
├─ abc2/
│  ├─ MATCHING_STRING/
│  │  ├─ xyz1
│  │  ├─ xyz2

After:

Main/
├─ abc1/
│  ├─ xyz2
│  ├─ xyz1
├─ abc2/
│  ├─ xyz2
│  ├─ xyz1

Comment: Where do want the files to be after the directory is gone? Might help if you gave a before/after example (just a few files) of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PowerShell for that (but you can also use the `find` command)

## find Option

You will lose files that have duplicate names

### The Folder before

```
~/test$ tree
.
├── abc1
│   └── string
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
└── abc2
    └── string
        ├── file1
        └── file2

4 directories, 4 files
```

### Execution

```
~/test$ for i in */string; do cd $(dirname $i); find . -type f -exec mv '{}' . \;;cd ..; done
```

### The Folder after

```
~/test$ tree
.
├── abc1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── string
└── abc2
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── string

4 directories, 4 files
```

[source for the find command](https://www.howtogeek.com/168164/move-files-into-one-directory-in-linux-with-find/)
[source for the loop](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/one-line-linux-commands)